# Firebase retrieving child nested data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data on with this value `7hmpcTuCAYQAYRqP7RNmnegSd9r2`

But i'm getting all four objects in snapshot. I want to get parent key values which contain this key
`7hmpcTuCAYQAYRqP7RNmnegSd9r2` 
Need to get blue mark keys.

Here is my code

```
     let ref = FirebaseManager.refs.databaseRoot.child("new_ChatListMembers")
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).queryEqual(toValue: true)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
    }
```

This code return four objects instead of two.Please help me how i can get specific data.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually using the query that you construct in your code. To use that, it'd be something like:

```
let ref = FirebaseManager.refs.databaseRoot.child("new_ChatListMembers")
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).queryEqual(toValue: true)
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
}
```

---

But this won't actually scale very well, as you'll need to define an index for each individual UID value in this structure. In short: your current data structure makes it each to find the users for a specific chat room, but it doesn't help finding the  chat rooms for a specific user.

To allow the latter, you'll want to add an extra structure in your data:

```
user_chats: {
  "$uid": {
    "$chatid": true
  }
}
```

So this is pretty much the inverse of what you have already, which is why this is often called an inverse index.

For more on this, and another example, see my answer here: [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Thank you for you response. Actually i was trying to follow this structure 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures

Comment: And that structure works great for when you only want to load the members for a room. If you also want to load the rooms for a member, you'll need what I show here and in the link. It is just another flat list in addition to the one(s) you already have.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll follow your guide in above mentioned link. Cheers